# Docker 1.9 Container stopping abruptly

Tags: docker

I have a docker container hosting a Java application. But many times I have seen application is down and docker is not running.

In `/var/log/daemon.log` I see only the below information with no errors

```
Oct 10 10:54:58 or4 docker[18366]: time="2016-10-10T10:54:58.875341257+05:30" level=info msg="POST /v1.21/containers/c1a64d308f45/stop?t=10"
Oct 10 10:54:59 or4 systemd-sysctl[100591]: Overwriting earlier assignment of net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle in file '/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf'.
```

Below is the output of `docker logs <container id>`

```
2016-10-10 10:53:57,242 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2016-10-10 10:53:57,243 INFO waiting for orchestrator to die
2016-10-10 10:53:57,243 INFO stopped: orchestrator (terminated by SIGTERM)
2016-10-10 11:31:21,137 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-10-10 11:31:21,137 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2016-10-10 11:31:21,170 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-10-10 11:31:21,170 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2016-10-10 11:31:21,171 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-10-10 11:31:21,171 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-10-10 11:31:22,174 INFO spawned: 'orchestrator' with pid 6
2016-10-10 11:31:23,863 INFO success: orchestrator entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-10-10 14:31:43,490 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2016-10-10 14:31:43,491 INFO waiting for orchestrator to die
2016-10-10 14:31:43,491 INFO stopped: orchestrator (terminated by SIGTERM)
2016-10-10 14:50:10,217 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-10-10 14:50:10,217 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2016-10-10 14:50:10,258 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-10-10 14:50:10,258 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2016-10-10 14:50:10,258 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-10-10 14:50:10,258 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-10-10 14:50:11,261 INFO spawned: 'orchestrator' with pid 6
2016-10-10 14:50:13,103 INFO success: orchestrator entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-10-10 14:57:48,522 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2016-10-10 14:57:48,522 INFO waiting for orchestrator to die
2016-10-10 14:57:48,523 INFO stopped: orchestrator (terminated by SIGTERM)
2016-10-10 15:43:04,028 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-10-10 15:43:04,028 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2016-10-10 15:43:04,059 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-10-10 15:43:04,059 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2016-10-10 15:43:04,059 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-10-10 15:43:04,059 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-10-10 15:43:05,061 INFO spawned: 'orchestrator' with pid 6
2016-10-10 15:43:06,561 INFO success: orchestrator entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Below is the docker file.

```
FROM nocindia/java:java8-mvn3.2.5
MAINTAINER "a@a.com"

RUN ln -fns /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip imagemagick mediainfo

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ENV SERVICEMIX_VERSION_MAJOR=F
ENV SERVICEMIX_VERSION_MINOR=I 
ENV SERVICEMIX_VERSION_PATCH=L.M2 
ENV SERVICEMIX_VERSION=${SERVICEMIX_VERSION_MAJOR}.${SERVICEMIX_VERSION_MINOR}.${SERVICEMIX_VERSION_PATCH} 
RUN wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/servicemix/servicemix-${SERVICEMIX_VERSION_MAJOR}/${SERVICEMIX_VERSION}/apache-servicemix-${SERVICEMIX_VERSION}.zip && \
    unzip -d /opt apache-servicemix-${SERVICEMIX_VERSION}.zip && \
    rm -f apache-servicemix-${SERVICEMIX_VERSION}.zip; 

#  For Karaf Web Console
EXPOSE 8181 

# Orchestrator service running inside karaf
EXPOSE XXXX

# For connecting to karaf console remotely via Karaf client
EXPOSE AAAA

# running mvn tests
EXPOSE BBBBB

# running file upload service
EXPOSE DDDDD

# remove the unwanted files which saves some MB's
RUN apt-get clean -y && apt-get autoclean -y && apt-get autoremove -y \
        && cp -R /usr/share/locale/en\@* /tmp/ && rm -rf /usr/share/locale/* && mv /tmp/en\@* /usr/share/locale/ \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/debconf/*-old && rm -rf /usr/share/doc/*

ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

ADD timezone /etc/timezone

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

`AAAA`, `XXXX` , etc are placeholders.

Can some one explain me what could be going wrong and how can I debug this issue?

Environment:-

- Docker 1.9
- Debian 8 64 Bit

Comment: Thanks! So your `orchestrator` process is receiving a SIGTERM, gets restarted and so on and so forth. Could that come from `supervisor` somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with Docker or any of its configuration. An external process was periodically restarting the docker which in turn was restarting the orchestrator process running inside docker.